Understanding how ANOVA works
Consider a one-way ANOVA consisting of two treatments 1 and 2 (argument easily extendable to multiple groups). The sum of squares within groups (SSE) is defined as $\sum\sum(X-\overline{X}_{j})^{2}$ and the sum of squares between groups (SSB) is defined as $\sum n_{j}(\overline{X}_{j}-\overline{X})^{2}$.
The definition of SSE makes sense to me as it is the deviation from group mean (an estimator of the mean for that group) of the values of the groups if they were considered to be coming from three different populations. Total sum of squares (SST) also makes sense if we think of it as deviation from overall mean, if they were all coming from the same population. But SSB doesn't make sense from the formula as each group's contribution is a product of the number of observations from that group and the deviation of that group's mean from overall mean, as if each group was reduced to just one value (which is their mean).
My understanding is that the formula for SSE and SST are consistent with their nomenclature, but SSB has been named so, only because the relation SST=SSB+SSE implies that consistently known SSE has been removed from SST, and the only remaining effect can be solely due to the treatments (or whatever the complement of SSE is). The formula hence doesn't make proper sense, but can be seen as just SST-SSE if I am pedantic enough. Is it right? If not, please help me with an intuition of the formula as to why the whole group was reduced to its mean. Sorry for being subjective in the meaning of 'sense'.

At the cost of being too simplistic, ANOVA is nothing but Cochran's theorem in disguise. There are numerous posts in our site; you can check them and may update your query. And welcome to CV.

I don't know what you mean by "doesn't make proper sense"  SSB is the sum of squares between, and that seems to me to be captured by the formula.

SST assesses how far the values are from the grand mean.
SSE assesses how far the values ar from their group means.
SSB assesss how far those group means are from the grand mean (taking into account sample sizes).

@User1865345 Thanks for referring me to the root - Cochran's theorem.

Mind you expand this as answer (for it seems so) @HarveyMotulsky.

@Harvey and Peter, from 'sense' I meant that if we want to give a formula (from scratch) for deviations from overall mean, we would do it exactly as the formula for SST says. Similarly for for the formula of SSE. But, if someone would have asked me for the formula for deviations of overall mean from group means (SSB) without knowing SST=SSE+SSB, I would have hesitated to give the current formula in cases especially where the variance was high because it seems unjust to reduce that whole data set to one point. So, I think its coming mathematically as just SST-SSE and we give it a name.
